# How can I export a React Component as an NPM package to use in separate projects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack, ecmascript-6

I have created a React component inside a project that I'd like to use in multiple projects.  At the moment, I only care about doing this locally and for development.  The React Component is rendered into the root div, the project uses webpack and babel to transpile JSX, ES6 and some ES7 features into a bundle.

I thought it would be simple to export this component such that I can simply run `npm install MyComponent` and begin using it in a fresh project.  However, I find it isn't so straight forward.  In particular, I've been reading for hours and hours and only seem to be getting more confused.

If my end goal is to keep developing 'MyComponent' in its containing project, while using 'MyComponent' in any number of other local projects, what are my options?  The first thing I did was change the `main` key of my `package.json` to `/src/components/MyComponent` and run `npm pack`.  This produces a `tgz` file I can install via its absolute filepath in other projects.  However, I found that the es6 and jsx was not being transpiled and so my client projects would be unable to parse `MyComponent`.  I then used webpack to transpile into `lib/MyComponent`, but when I have `import MyComponent from './path/to/MyComponent-1.0.0.tgz` I'd only see `{}` (an empty object) in the console.

Searching for solutions to my problem turn up many different approaches pulling together NPM, Grunt, Gulp, Babel, Webpack, etc..  And I am worried it will be many many more hours (days?) before I can grind that down to something understandable.

Given my requirements, what is the simplest solution I can implement to 1) compile down my React Component to the simplest to import module 2) import it into any local projects 3) continue to develop the package in the original host project and have changes easily propagate to client projects.

Answer (score 10):

In general, if you're going to begin creating `React` components as separated packages (which is a great pattern, for all the reasons you've already mentioned) - you're going to need to get at least a bit familiar with `webpack` and `babel`. There's a ton to learn here, but let me try to point you in the right direction:

```
// webpack.config.js

/* eslint-disable */
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')

const ENVIRONMENT = process.env.NODE_ENV
const PRODUCTION = ENVIRONMENT === 'production'
const SOURCEMAP = !PRODUCTION || process.env.SOURCEMAP

const library = 'your-lib-name' // << RENAME THIS <<
const filename = PRODUCTION ? `${library}.min.js` : `${library}.js`

const plugins = []

if (PRODUCTION) {
  plugins.push(
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(ENVIRONMENT),
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      minimize: true,
      output: { comments: false, semicolons: false },
      sourceMap: SOURCEMAP,
    })
  )
}

module.exports = {
  devtool: SOURCEMAP ? 'source-map' : 'none',
  entry:  `${__dirname}/path/to/your/component.js`, // << RENAME THIS <<
  externals: {
    'react': 'react',
    'react-dom': 'react-dom',
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test:    /\.js$/,
      loader:  'babel-loader',
      exclude: /node_modules/,
    }],
  },
  output: {
    filename,
    library,
    path:           `${__dirname}/lib`,
    libraryTarget:  'umd',
    umdNamedDefine: true,
  },
  plugins,
}
```

I know that looks like a bunch - but it handles the majority of what you're going to want. In specific:

1. If you specify `NODE_ENV=production` when building, this will uglify/minify your package, and do some other trimming which you may want later.
2. Building with this script will output a `sourcemap`, which you can use with dev tools to inspect your minified code in the debugger window, among other things.
3. This marks `react` and `react-dom` as `externals` - which means they won't get bundled up and packaged *inside* your bundle. This is great - because it means you won't get 2+ copies of `react`'s filesize just because you've `import`ed your own component!

To use it, though, you now need some `package.json` love.

```
package.json

{
  "name": "Your Name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "This is my awesome react package!",
  "main": "path/to/your/component.js",
  "author": "Your Name",
  "license": "MIT",
  "repository": { /* Your Repo Info Here */ },
  "dependencies": {
    "any-packages-you-need-included-in-builds": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.22.2",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.22.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "webpack": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "yarn prebuild && NODE_ENV=production webpack",
    "prebuild": "mkdir -p ./lib && rm -rf ./lib/*"
  }
}
```

Obviously, you can have a lot more here if you need it - such as other `babel-plugin-*` plugins that you use in your transpilation, other packages, etc.But this set will let your `webpack` build run. Note that the scripts here assume you're using `yarn` - so that you can run `yarn build`, and that you're on a posix system, for `mkdir` to work. If you're on windows or not using `yarn`, just update the scripts accordingly.

The rest is just learning to publish your package to `npm` or another package repository. Primarily, that's just setting the `version` number in `package.json` to something new (`npm version`) and then publishing (`npm publish`). You will have to have an `npm` account for this, of course - and be logged in (`npm login`).

Once you've published to `npm` you can just `yarn add your-package-name`.

Remember, though - we marked `react` and `react-dom` as `external` - so in the consuming package, you'll need to make sure they're available as `window.React` and `window.ReactDOM` - or you'll need to include the component directly from `node_modules/your-package-name/path/to/your/component.js`

Comment: so i really appreciate the in depth answer.  I really was just looking for the straight path to sharing the package across projects locally.  so the parts about accounting for develop/production, publishing to the npm registry were beyond the scope of my desires.  perhaps, I should learn to do all this properly or not at all.. 
 i did find that `npm install ../projects/HostProject` will let me import the component to another project and updates to the HostProject's component will be reflected in client projects after I run webpack. of course any changes to file system layout will break things

Comment: That totally makes sense. For your local development purposes - that's probably great. `yarn` now also has a `workspace` concept - which may solve what you're looking for, and you might also look at `yarn link` (or `npm link`) - which will let you use a local project as a dependency for local development, without the publish/update process to the repo being necessary.

Comment: Also - as @Sidney mentions (https://stackoverflow.com/a/46166499/1454806) - you can just create a GitHub repo and `npm` or `yarn` add it directly. `yarn add username:reponame`

Comment: npm link turns out to be very helpful.  the only downside i'm seeing is that any 'npm install..' seems to clear out the link

Comment: I've found it a little troublesome to use as well. I think the intent of `npm link` is to allow you to simply work on two+ separate packages at the same time, without having to republish each of them for every iteration. Once you do something beyond that (such as actually upping the version number of installed packages) things seem to go strangely wrong in various ways.

You might want to look at `yarn` - which has similar functionality, and iirc also has some additional apis for working cross-package.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to `npm pack` a package to use it. If you make your component into a git repo and put it on Github, you can use NPM to install it directly from Github by using `npm install alex/mycomponent` where `alex` is your github username and `mycomponent` is the repo name. Re-running that command will re-install from Github, in case you make changes to the repo.

Once you're happy with the component, you can upload it to the NPM registry to install like any other package (`npm install name`). Using Github at first makes it a bit easier to develop.

Webpack might not compile things from `node_modules` by default. Usually, packages are pre-compiled before being published anyway, but you should be able to configure webpack to build your 'packaged' component, along with the rest of your app. Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38008149/7486612

Answer (score 1):

In order to push react libraries into NPM, you may need some boilerplate which will install and convert many things for you (and you can still use your current react module as the main source, just follow the guides at the end of my answer, then you will surely get all the ideas)

Or you can also refer to my previous answer to a similar question:
[Issue with publishing to npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43626034/issue-with-publishing-to-npm/43626295#43626295)

=====

I've also pushed several react libraries successfully into NPM:

https://www.npmjs.com/~thinhvo0108

=====

Your github repositories' folder structure should also look like mine:

https://github.com/thinhvo0108/react-paypal-express-checkout

=====

**Useful tutorial below here:**

(boilerplate source) https://github.com/juliancwirko/react-npm-boilerplate

(author's article) http://julian.io/creating-react-npm-packages-with-es2015/

Answer (score 0):

Start by looking at existing component library, eg [Material UI](http://www.material-ui.com/#/get-started/installation).
Specifically check out npm scripts they have (see package.json):

```
"build:es2015": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production babel ./src --ignore *.spec.js --out-dir ./build",
"build:es2015modules": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production BABEL_ENV=modules babel ./src/index.js --out-file ./build/index.es.js",
"build:copy-files": "babel-node ./scripts/copy-files.js",
"build:umd:dev": "webpack --config scripts/umd.webpack.config.js",
"build:umd:prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config scripts/umd.webpack.config.js",
"build": "npm run build:es2015 && npm run build:es2015modules && npm run build:copy-files && npm run build:umd:dev && npm run build:umd:prod",
```

That's example of very involved and high quality component library, that makes sure that regardless of your build pipeline you'll be able to use it.

Setting up build process with webpack might be cumbersome, but don't concentrate on that too much from the begining, and cover cases that are most straight forward to you.

Also check out https://storybook.js.org/ while working on your components.